# How to convert mysql table to mongoose schema?

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, mongodb, mongoose

In particular from what I have read so far on Mongoose I no longer have to specify the length of the fields.

For example, Currently I have.

[list of fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYavA.png)

and I want to create a Mongoose Schema from this kind of like:

```
  var UserSchema = new Schema({ 
    id: String,
    id_google: String,
    type: String,
    name: String,
    email: String,
    timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    pic_url: String
  });
```

Here is one [reference](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) I found which I have used to fill all of the fields.  Is it this simple or am I missing something?

I don't see any reason to store the IDs as numbers anymore.  But if I wanted to I could substitute with Number.

Comment: with two exceptions, your schema looks fine. first, the third property, "type", is going to cause you issues, type is a reserved keyword for mongoose, you even used it correctly in your "timestamp" property. for another, mongoose has a built in _id property given to all mongoose objects without the need for you specify it in your schema, its of type mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId

Comment: Possible duplicate of [converting database from mysql to mongoDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251548/converting-database-from-mysql-to-mongodb)